# What does the term "trivial" formally mean in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I found the term in this chain of concepts:

- (1) trivially copyable constructor
- (2) trivial defaut constructor (defined from (1) )
- (3) trivialType (defined from(2)) 
  Techinically, I understand all the concepts (like what exactly it contains)
  Semantically, I don't understand the term "trivial" (explain why I keep forgeting the chain).
  I try to look up the word in as many dictionaries as possible, but no sense of it make sense to me, and here is my work (if any one care): 
  --------------------
  *trivial:

1. of little value or importance.
   [OXF] not important or serious; not worth considering
   =>a trivial detail
   =>I know it sounds trivial, but I'm worried about it.
   =>huge fines were imposed for trivial offenses
   ---------
   1X. A trivial problem = is easy to solve:
   Getting computers to understand human language is not a trivial problem.
   ----------
2. relating to or being the mathematically simplest case: specifically, characterized by having "all variables" equal to "zero"
   [DIC] noting "a solution of an equation" in which "the value of every variable" of "the equation" is equal to zero.
   =>a trivial solution to a linear equation
   ----------
   2X. (of a theorem, proof, or the like) simple, transparent, or immediately evident.
   =>NONE
   ---------
3. (of names of organisms) specific, as distinguished from generic.
   [MER] SPECIFIC sense 4
   =>NONE
   --------
4. commonplace; ordinary.
   [MER] COMMONPLACE, ORDINARY
   =>NONE
   ---------------------
   I read all the concepts in the chain, and seem to understand them all. And then a few days later, I see one of that terms again and it seems like a stranger to me again. So I have to read the whole chain again. And a few days later it happens again. And I find myself in an infinate loop.
   So what the term "trivial" semantically or literally mean in C++ and why the term is chosen, please help.

Comment: "Simple, transparent, or immediately evident" covers it.

Comment: ...or "being the mathematically simplest case". Those nicely describe functions that do a bytewise copy or do nothing.

Comment: @user207421 , meaning like: a simply eligible copy constructor? "a simple/transperant defaut constructor? still not very  make sense to me yet :D

Comment: The terms are defined in the standard (e.g. https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-3).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh. it seems to make sense better a little bit

Comment: Where did you see "trivially eligible copy constructor"? Shouldn't it be "trivial eligible copy constructor"? Where "trivial" and "eligible" apply separately, and "trivial" means that it does a bytewise copy, which is the simplest way of copying.

Comment: You shouldn't use a standard dictionary, but look in the C++ standard document, which has specific definitions for this, For example http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop defines *trivially copyable class* and *trivial class*.

Comment: @Mat  , thanks but I'm looking for the sematic meaning, not technical one. I have read it more than one but keep forgeting it because don't understand the underlying term :)

Comment: @Crackie: this is a site for programming questions, not English.

Comment: @Mat I would argue that the language  ISO documents are written in, should be called English++. OOP structure there is evident.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's "trivially copyable contructor" :) didn't expect someone can spot it :D

Comment: @HolyBlackCat here is where I found it, at "Trivially copyable class" section: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivial_class

Comment: @BoP Understanding the origin of a term is important to intuitively understand the term (as can be seen here; OP keeps forgetting the meaning because he doens't know its origin).

Comment: @Crackie Mhm, it doesn't say "trivially eligible" anywhere. It just says "trivial" and "eligible" separately.

Comment: Basically, any object or variable named `x`  is "trivially copyable" if `y = x` doesn't require a custom (or non-default) copy constructor or similar assignment operator overload.  Integers, floats, pointers, for example. Structs and Classes without a copy constructor or overloaded assignment operator are another example.  `struct {int x; floaty; char* c;}` is trivaly copyable.  `std::string` and `std::vector` are not.

Comment: @Crackie there is no underlying term. Technical document chooses closest appropriate word and then defines its meaning strictly in context of such document. another document may have  a different definition or it would reference a document which does that definition. Taht's the principle of a legal document writing. ISO C++ standard defines what "must", "may", "can", and "maybe" mean, heh

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh. right. I thought we can combine near-by stuff to make it more effectively :D

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Really , I thought it should be a reason to make Bjarne Stroustrup chose that terms? or perhaps he's drunk at the time he named it :>

Comment: @selbie it sounds like the right answer :)

Comment: @Crackie Afaik, there are at least three principles a) it should't sound like oxymoron (don't call something complex or uncommon 'trivial" or "generic") , b) it shouldn't sound similar to another term or repeat it, c) it should be defined in non-contradicting and commutative way (e.g. if we define what "trivial", opposite of it is defined "non-trivial", etc). The reason for particular word is likely meaning (2) in your list. Programming is a discipline of applied mathematics.

Comment: Some definition of terms in ISO standard sound funny because of those approaches: `An ill-formed program is a program which is not well-formed.`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie wow. your logic sounds so accurate. I didn't expect someone understand things that deep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be rather a translation or linguistics question?

`Trivially X-ble` and `trivial Y` are terms defined by noramtive document of C++. For class-type (this is another term) to be trivially-constructible, it shouldn't have a default-constructor removed or defined by user (the programmer). Consequently it cannot have ANY constructor defined by user, because such would remove the default one.

A *trivial default constructor* is one which was not defined by user, therefore it's a *simplest case* of a default constructor.

You cannot read the standard using a common-language dictionary. It's a document written in legalese, it defines every term it uses. Even what auxilary verbs in its text would mean (that's common across all ISO standards).

Comment: I understand everything now, shouldn't forget it again. thank a lot :D

Comment: "_to be trivially-constructible, it shouldn't have a default-constructor removed or defined by user (the programmer)._": An implicitly-defined default constructor does not at all need to be trivial. "_Consequently it cannot have ANY constructor defined by user_": A user-declared default constructor defaulted on its first declaration is still potentially a trivial default constructor.

Comment: *"Consequently it cannot have ANY constructor defined by user, because such would remove the default one."* This is simply not true, a type can have a defaulted default constructor and a user defined constructor and still be trivial (e.g.: `struct t { t() = default; t(int) {} };`).

Comment: @303 `t() = default;` is considered a defined constructor, it's just defined as default, even if you wouldn't have `t(int) {} `, you lready made `t`  non-agregate. Unless it's very first definition it,  it might not be even trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Terms such as *trivial* are defined in the C++ standard, and you can look up their definitions. Those are most easily found [in the index of the latest working draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex).

Intuitively, a *trivial type* is a type where all operations (default construction, copying, destruction, ...) are equivalent to doing nothing, or performing `std::memmove` from one object to another (ignoring padding). `int` is a trivial type for example, since construction and destruction of an `int` requires no action, and copying it is just copying its bytes (as if by `std::memmove`).

Formally, [[basic.types.general] p9](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#9) defines what a *trivial type* is. In short, it's a *scalar type* (e.g. `int`, `void*`, etc.), an array of trivial types, or a *trivial class*.

> A *trivial* class is a class that is [trivially copyable](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#def:type,trivially_copyable) and has one or more eligible [default constructors](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor), all of which are trivial.

- [[class.prop] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#2)

> A default constructor is *trivial* if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - [...]

- [[class.default.ctor] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#3)

In short, it means that a default constructor "has to do nothing" to be trivial. From this and other definitions, you can figure out exactly what the C++ standard means by *trivial*.

Comment: thanks @Jan Schulkle. it was a great help :)

Comment: "_or performing std::memmove from one object to another_": A trivial constructor/assignment is not equivalent to a std::memmove, except for unions. The trivial operations do not have to copy padding, nor do they have to replicate the object/value representations, only the values. I think a better description would that these functionalities behave as in C.

Comment: @user17732522 requirements of `std::memmove` are *TriviallyCopyable* and non-overlapping objects since C++11. Yeah, default constructor or alternate constructors are not considered for `std::memmove` after C++11 but potential result might be undesired (but not undefined). "C-compatible class" would be  *standard-layout class* in C++ and is a much stricter requirement.

Comment: "_requirements of std::memmove are_": I am not talking about `std::memmove`'s preconditions. I am talking about the behavior of trivial special member functions. "_Yeah, default constructor or alternate constructors are not considered for std::memmove after C++11_": `std::memmove` never considers any constructors, in no C++ version. "_"C-compatible class" would be standard-layout class in C++ and is a much stricter requirement._": standard-layout and trivial are orthogonal, both together imply POD, i.e. completely C-like. I am talking about the _behavioral_ part, not _compatibility_.